# PyMongo clear array within nested array

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, pymongo

Im trying to clear the `hwids_used` Array. I added a screenshot below. I'm not quite sure what query i would need to use. I wanna find by `user`. I think i need the `find_one_and_update` method/function. But i have no clue what the query would be exactly

[image]

```py
mycol.find_one_and_update({"user": username}, {"$set":{???}})
```

That's atleast what i think.

Comment: _"clear array"_ means delete the field `hwids_used` _or_ delete the elements of the array to make it empty?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB - Clearing items in a nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137170/mongodb-clearing-items-in-a-nested-array)